# ASP.NET: Implementing a client server solution (for chats, iterative fights ect)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax, client-server

I have a quite advanced application, where I need to add some client/server functionality. Some examples of functionalities is:

- Chat
- One vs. one fight in a browser game
- Draw people on a map

I am creating this application in ASP.NET and AJAX. I do not use Silverlight/Java Applet/Flash or anything else. If possible, I do not want to change this for other reasons.

I thought about creating some kind of game server, and then communicating either web services or TCP protocol: But I have NO idea if this is a good idea. Also, I don't know how to do this.

So my question is:
What's the best way to implement this? And is it even possible? And if it is, could you give a reference or two?

**Thanks a lot**,

Lars

Comment: Ajax is a vague term. JQuery, Atlas, UpdatePanels, manually calling web-services via JavaScript, what? With the exception of the updatepanel the answer is yes you can do that with all three items.... though depending on the "fight" you are talking about you may have to do html 5 stuff.

Comment: I don't require any specific techniques as long as we don't have to bring Silverlight/others alike into the picture: If it works it's great! But how would you avoid using a database using the terms above when creating for instance a database?

Comment: *"But how would you avoid using a database using the terms above when creating for instance a database?"* I'm afraid that question doesn't make even the slightest bit of sense. :/ What have databases to do with your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing chat & multiplayer games, the crux of the problem is in getting the server to asynchronously send messages to the client. This can be accomplished by a method called reverse-Ajax (or commet). Here is a simple example for how to do reverse-Ajax with ASP.NET. This is a very involved concept (at least until we can use HTML5 WebSockets) with a lot of thought going into security concerns, et al. I assume that by asking this question you are already quite familiar with Ajax & browser scripting (if not, you have a lot of reading to do).

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial on writing a basic chat server: (in c# no less)
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33396-basic-clientserver-chat-application-in-c%23/

Sgive you a good foundation on server development.