# Application state in ASP.NET - performance limitations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, global-variables

I have an application where I want two users to communicate with eachother.. This has to happen every second - and I have been considering a lot of solutions.

[I had a thread some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557428/asp-net-implementing-a-client-server-solution-for-chats-iterative-fights-ect), which gave some really good ideas. Problem is I don't want to get into reverse-AJAX yet as I am waiting for HTML 5 sockets.

Anyway, I "just" need to create a variety of features: Chat, 1 on 1 fight, people on a map and alike. For this, I see two obvious solutions:

- Database updates (read from DB every second)
- Using the global Application state

Which of these solutions are the best? Or do you have some even more magic neat solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at [MemCached](http://www.memcached.org/).  You can run it on a separate server and have multiple servers share if you need it to be.  If you need it to be persistent -- there is [MemCachedDB](http://memcachedb.org/)

Comment: Good idea :) Do you (or anyone else?) have an opinion about the application/db solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a really great [comet framework](http://www.frozenmountain.com/) for that, it's dead easy to use and it also supports html 5 sockets (as well as normal reverse-AJAX). If persistence is not a requirement than I don't see any reasons not to use it. There are other free alternatives too, but none of them are using C# as far as I know.

Comment: It seems quite expensive - but most likely the best solution. Thanks for sharing!
You should not happen to have an opinion about the application/db solution?

Comment: There are billion ways to do it. Facebook uses Erlang for their chat, which has a distributed DB called mnesia and a comet server. MemCached is also a good option, but you will have to glue it to the application yourself.